# elasticsearch does not delete all records because of version conflict

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have php app with elasticsearch 6.2.1
my request

```
    $delete = [
  'index' => 'myIndex',


  'type' => 'mytype',
            'conflicts' => 'proceed',
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                    'match' => [
                        "category_name" => 'myname'
                    ]
                ],
            ]
        ];
        $response = $this->client->deleteByQuery($delete);
```

I got this response

```
Array
(
    [took] => 1
    [timed_out] => 
    [total] => 3
    [deleted] => 0
    [batches] => 1
    [version_conflicts] => 3
    [noops] => 0
    [retries] => Array
        (
            [bulk] => 0
            [search] => 0
        )

    [throttled_millis] => 0
    [requests_per_second] => -1
    [throttled_until_millis] => 0
    [failures] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

After this it does not delete any records.  [deleted] => 0
why it does not delete?

What does it mean ?
[version_conflicts] => 3

Answer (score 1):

From the ElasticSearch documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query

`_delete_by_query`

> gets a snapshot of the index when it starts and deletes what it finds
>   using internal versioning. **That means that you’ll get a version
>   conflict if the document changes between the time when the snapshot
>   was taken and when the delete request is processed**. *When the versions
>   match the document is deleted*.

I had the same problem some day back, but when I used `conflicts=proceed` it worked for me on Kibana console. So it should work for you also with PHP.

```
POST /properties/_delete_by_query/?conflicts=proceed
{
    "query" : { 
        "match_all" : {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conflicts = proceed

```
POST /properties/_delete_by_query/?conflicts=proceed
{
    "query" : { 
        "match_all" : {}
    }
}
```

Note: This query will just ignore the version_conflicts and proceed to delete the documents that can be deleted. Means, it might not delete everything.